# kaminari doesn't work on models loaded from a gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid, kaminari

I have multiple projects which need to access the same database for different reasons. That's why I created a shared Ruby gem with the models. In my rails application I'm using rails 6.X and mongoid 7.X. When I'm adding kaminari, the pagination works fine for the models which are directly defined in the rails project. But for models which are loaded from my shared gem, the pagination does not work. Always getting the error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `total_pages' for #<Mongoid::Criteria:0x00007fc09a2e7428>)
```

What I have to do to make it work with models loaded from a gem?

Comment: A last resort is by making your models kaminari arrays, like `Kaminari.paginate_array(mongoid_model_instance)` you’ll hace page, per, next_page

Comment: Now I'm getting `NoMethodError (undefined method total_pages for #<Kaminari::PaginatableArray:0x00007ff68e6eb158>)`

Comment: The code snippet which causes this error is: `<%= paginate Kaminari.paginate_array(@orga.project_scans) %>`.

Comment: OK. Works now! Like this `<%= paginate Kaminari.paginate_array(@orga.project_scans.desc(:created_at)).page(0) %>`

Comment: Cool, glad it worked!

Comment: Does that load all documents then on each request? For the original problem, if you create an application reproducing the problem I will look into why it's not working.